# Как правильно написать триггер

Tags: mysql

Первый раз пишу триггер, скажите в чем может быть проблема.

Есть первая таблица `(table)`, а в нем значение количество `(qt)`. В зависимости от количество, во второй таблице должен создаваться поле `(num)`. Значение поле выполняется как нумерация, поэтому он должен взять последний значению и автоматический записать дальше. 
Нап: если последний значения `(table2:num)` было 2, а количество `(table:num)` 3, начиная с 3 он должен записаться `(3,4,5) (table2:num)`. 
Триггер создался, но проблема в том что не чего не происходить после `insert : table`
Скажите что я написала не так, и почему оно создалось, но не чего не делает?

Вот триггер которую писала:

```
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `t_mat $$`
CREATE

TRIGGER `t_mat` AFTER INSERT ON `table` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE num2 INT;
SET i=1;
SET num2=(SELECT MAX(num) FROM table2);
WHILE i<= new.qt  DO
    SET num2=num2+1;
    INSERT INTO table2(num_mat, pole2,pole3) VALUES(num2,new.id_m,new.ps);
    SET i=i+1; 
END WHILE;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: И потом использовать цикл внутри триггера норм или нет?

Comment: У вас ничего не происходит потому что вы не инициализировали счетчик цикла `i`

Comment: И не определена переменная num2. А вот переменная num определена, но не используется.

Comment: вот так изменила, код но теперь дает ошибку, с в строке `SET num2=num2+1`

Comment: Спасибо вам Anamnian и  Akin, что нашли мои ошибки. Теперь с удовольствием буду писать триггер, а то раньше думала что это не для меня.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось.

`DELIMITER $$`

`CREATE`
   `/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER t_mol AFTER INSERT ON table
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE num2 INT;
    SET i=1;
    SET num2=(SELECT MAX(num_mat) FROM table2);
    WHILE i<=new.qt DO
        SET num2=num2+1;
        INSERT INTO table2(num_mat,pole2,pole3) VALUES (num2,new.id_m,new.ps);
        SET i=i+1;
    END WHILE;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;` 
Спасибо всем вам за то, что не оставили без внимание!